# AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4c0bc4 has not been refreshed yet

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting stack trace for following code,

```
public interface SequenceDAO {

    public Sequence getSequence(String sequenceId);

    public int getNextValue(String sequenceId);
}
```

``````````````````````````````````````````

```
public class Sequence {
    private int initial;
    private String prefix;
    private String suffix;

    public Sequence(int initial, String prefix, String suffix) {
        this.initial = initial;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }
```

````````````````````````````````````````````````

```
@Component("SequenceDAO")
public class SequenceDAOImpl implements SequenceDAO {

    private Map<String, Sequence> sequences;
    private Map<String, Integer> values;

    public SequenceDAOImpl() {
        sequences = new HashMap<>();
        sequences.put("IT", new Sequence(30, "IT", "A"));
        values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("IT", 10000);
    }

    @Override
    public Sequence getSequence(String sequenceId) {
        return sequences.get(sequenceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getNextValue(String sequenceId) {
        int value = values.get(sequenceId);
        values.put(sequenceId, value + 1);
        return value;
    }

}
```

``````````````````````````````````````````````

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.example");
        SequenceDAO obj = context.getBean("SequenceDAO", SequenceDAO.class);
        System.out.println(obj.getNextValue("IT"));
        System.out.println(obj.getSequence("IT"));
    }
```

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4c0bc4 has not been refreshed yet
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1059)
    at com.example.SpringAnnotationsSequenceGeneratorWithDaoIntroductionApplication.main(SpringAnnotationsSequenceGeneratorWithDaoIntroductionApplication.java:14)
```

Iam new to spring and I am learning spring without annotations , so if anyone can tell me what happend wrong here

any help is appericiated.

Beat Regards

Comment: You forgot `context.refresh()` after the `context.scan`.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum actually I am learning from book(Apress.Spring.3rd.Edition.) which have the following example but `context.refresh()` is not mentioned there. thanks again for help

Answer (score 1):

Your context `init` should like this:

```
ApplicationContext aContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConcertConfig.class);
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
public class ConcertConfig {

}
```